# Calling OpenWeatherMap API in Leaflet.js map

Tags: leaflet, openweathermap-api

How to get weather data from OpenWeatherMap API in a popup by clicking any location on the map?

i am still new at calling APIs in my map, API return JSON files but i don't know how to call the API in my map and how to bind JSON file in an HTML element.

This is the API which uses coordinates to return weather data in a JSON file: api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139

but i need to replace these lat and lng parameters by clicking any location on the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this

```js
var mymap = L.map('maptest').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; OSM contributors'
}).addTo(mymap)

var popup = L.popup()

function onMapClick(e) {
    popup
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .setContent("Fetching weather info")
        .openOn(mymap);

    fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + e.latlng.lat + '&lon=' + e.latlng.lng + '&appid=' + yourApiKey)
        .then(r => r.json()) 
        .then(data => { 
            // Change this line to show exactly the info you need
            popup.setContent(data.weather.map(w => w.description).join(", "))
        })
}

mymap.on('click', onMapClick)
```

The example is using the `fetch` api to call the openweathermap api and `fetch` is only supported in modern browsers. If you need to support older browsers you need to use a polyfill (https://github.com/github/fetch)

Edit: As mentioned by @Spacedman in the comments, the above solution should only be used on private networks. If you use the above code on public available networks, you expose your apikey for openweathermap so that anyone can use it to request the service.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it is very useful
but i need to show infos that returns from the API in the popup
sample of infos:
{"coord":
{"lon":145.77,"lat":-16.92},
"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],
"base":"cmc stations",
"main":{"temp":293.25,"pressure":1019,"humidity":83,"temp_min":289.82,"temp_max":295.37},
"wind":{},
"clouds":{"all":75},
"rain":{"3h":3},
"dt":1435658272,
"sys":{"type":1,"id":8166,"message":0.0166,"country":"AU","sunrise":1435610796,"sunset":1435650870},
"id":2172797,
"name":"Cairns",
"cod":200}

Comment: Note that if you make this map public then anyone can see your API key and reuse it themselves.

Comment: @EslamFarag: You have access to all the data that are returned from the api in the variable `data` that is defined in the function that set the content of the popup

Comment: @Spacedman: Thanks. That is a very important detail. I'll update the answer to include your comment.

Comment: i just need an example to show other element in the popup like "sunset".

Comment: If you want to show the sunset info you can change the line `popup.setContent(data.weather.map(w => w.description).join(", "))` to `popup.setContent("Sunset: " + data.sys.sunset)`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve something like this:

[image]
[image]

you can use the following code. Just copy paste and save it as .html file.
The comments in the script should explain whats going on. If not, let me know. It is a modified and simplified map of mine I made some time ago, so I might have missed something to remove or adjust which may cause confusion. Dont forget to insert your personal API key.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Openweathermap</title>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.4.0/leaflet.css" />
<style>
#headline
{
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 2px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#map
{
    position: absolute; 
    height: 90vh;
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 99.5vw;
    min-width: 200px;
    left: 2px;  
    border: 3px solid;
    border-color: grey;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    z-index: -2;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.4.0/leaflet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

<p id='headline'><b>Openweathermap</b></p>

<!-- mapbox -->
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<!-- routing -->


<br>
<!-- links !-->


<!-- custom script!-->
<script>
//MAP
var mymap = L.map('map', {
    center: [48.7, 11.5],
    zoom: 6,
    zoomControl: false,
});

//BASEMAPS
var osm = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
{
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright" target = "_blank">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(mymap);



var popup = L.popup();

//popup function
function onMapClick(e) {
    popup
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString()) //esample from leaflet, will be immediately replaced by weatherpopup...
        .openOn(mymap);


//getting json function
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + e.latlng.lat + '&lon=' + e.latlng.lng + "&appid=INSERTYOURAPIKEYHERE",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      // storing json data in variables
      weatherlocation_lon = data.coord.lon; // lon WGS84
      weatherlocation_lat = data.coord.lat; // lat WGS84
      weatherstationname = data.name // Name of Weatherstation
      weatherstationid = data.id // ID of Weatherstation
      weathertime = data.dt // Time of weatherdata (UTC)
      temperature = data.main.temp; // Kelvin
      airpressure = data.main.pressure; // hPa
      airhumidity = data.main.humidity; // %
      temperature_min = data.main.temp_min; // Kelvin
      temperature_max = data.main.temp_max; // Kelvin
      windspeed = data.wind.speed; // Meter per second
      winddirection = data.wind.deg; // Wind from direction x degree from north
      cloudcoverage = data.clouds.all; // Cloudcoverage in %
      weatherconditionid = data.weather[0].id // ID
      weatherconditionstring = data.weather[0].main // Weatheartype
      weatherconditiondescription = data.weather[0].description // Weatherdescription
      weatherconditionicon = data.weather[0].icon // ID of weathericon

    // Converting Unix UTC Time
    var utctimecalc = new Date(weathertime * 1000);
    var months = ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12'];
    var year = utctimecalc.getFullYear();
    var month = months[utctimecalc.getMonth()];
    var date = utctimecalc.getDate();
    var hour = utctimecalc.getHours();
    var min = utctimecalc.getMinutes();
    var sec = utctimecalc.getSeconds();
    var time = date + '.' + month + '.' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + min + ' Uhr';

    // recalculating
    var weathercondtioniconhtml = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + weatherconditionicon + ".png";
    var weathertimenormal = time; // reallocate time var....
    var temperaturecelsius = Math.round((temperature - 273) * 100) / 100;  // Converting Kelvin to Celsius
    var windspeedknots = Math.round((windspeed * 1.94) * 100) / 100; // Windspeed from m/s in Knots; Round to 2 decimals
    var windspeedkmh = Math.round((windspeed * 3.6) * 100) / 100; // Windspeed from m/s in km/h; Round to 2 decimals
    var winddirectionstring = "Im the wind from direction"; // Wind from direction x as text
    if (winddirection > 348.75 &&  winddirection <= 11.25) {
        winddirectionstring =  "North";
    } else if (winddirection > 11.25 &&  winddirection <= 33.75) {
        winddirectionstring =  "Northnortheast";
    } else if (winddirection > 33.75 &&  winddirection <= 56.25) {
        winddirectionstring =  "Northeast";
    } else if (winddirection > 56.25 &&  winddirection <= 78.75) {
        winddirectionstring =  "Eastnortheast";
    } else if (winddirection > 78.75 &&  winddirection <= 101.25) {
        winddirectionstring =  "East";
    } else if (winddirection > 101.25 &&  winddirection <= 123.75) {
        winddirectionstring =  "Eastsoutheast";
    } else if (winddirection > 123.75 &&  winddirection <= 146.25) {
        winddirectionstring =  "Southeast";
    } else if (winddirection > 146.25 &&  winddirection <= 168.75) {
        winddirectionstring =  "Southsoutheast";
    } else if (winddirection > 168.75 &&  winddirection <= 191.25) {
        winddirectionstring =  "South";
    } else if (winddirection > 191.25 &&  winddirection <= 213.75) {
        winddirectionstring =  "Southsouthwest";
    } else if (winddirection > 213.75 &&  winddirection <= 236.25) {
        winddirectionstring =  "Southwest";
    } else if (winddirection > 236.25 &&  winddirection <= 258.75) {
        winddirectionstring =  "Westsouthwest";
    } else if (winddirection > 258.75 &&  winddirection <= 281.25) {
        winddirectionstring =  "West";
    } else if (winddirection > 281.25 &&  winddirection <= 303.75) {
        winddirectionstring =  "Westnorthwest";
    } else if (winddirection > 303.75 &&  winddirection <= 326.25) {
        winddirectionstring =  "Northwest";
    } else if (winddirection > 326.25 &&  winddirection <= 348.75) {
        winddirectionstring =  "Northnorthwest";
    } else {
        winddirectionstring =  " - currently no winddata available - ";
    };

//Popup with content
    var fontsizesmall = 1;
    popup.setContent("Weatherdata:<br>" + "<img src=" + weathercondtioniconhtml + "><br>" + weatherconditionstring + " (Weather-ID: " + weatherconditionid + "): " + weatherconditiondescription + "<br><br>Temperature: " + temperaturecelsius + "°C<br>Airpressure: " + airpressure + " hPa<br>Humidityt: " + airhumidity + "%" + "<br>Cloudcoverage: " + cloudcoverage + "%<br><br>Windspeed: " + windspeedkmh + " km/h<br>Wind from direction: " + winddirectionstring + " (" + winddirection + "°)" + "<br><br><font size=" + fontsizesmall + ">Datasource:<br>openweathermap.org<br>Measure time: " + weathertimenormal + "<br>Weatherstation: " + weatherstationname + "<br>Weatherstation-ID: " + weatherstationid + "<br>Weatherstation Coordinates: " + weatherlocation_lon + ", " + weatherlocation_lat);           


    },
    error: function() {
      alert("error receiving wind data from openweathermap");
    }
  });        
});
//getting json function ends here

//popupfunction ends here
}

//popup
mymap.on('click', onMapClick);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

To receive the .json data from openweathermap I'm using jquery ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + e.latlng.lat + '&lon=' + e.latlng.lng + "&appid=134c379c7ae600ae9be14acedade3faf",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      // storing json data in variables
      weatherlocation_lon = data.coord.lon; // lon WGS84
```

Where to find what data is described at https://openweathermap.org/current